# How much input voltage is required to get 12V from an LM2596?

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, wifi, 12v, lead-acid

I am trying to run a WiFi router from a 12V lead acid UPS battery.

To get a stable 12V output from the battery I used an LM2596.

The problem is that the output is always 8.28V-8.50V. No matter how many times I spin the potentiometer the output is 8.28V.

Is this a wrong approach to get stable 12V DC from a 12V lead acid battery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LM2596 is a buck converter. It can only lower voltage. The parameter you are interested in is called ["dropout voltage"](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf). To get stabilized 12V from an "approximate" 12V source you need a buck-boost converter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sharing the details about the 'dropout voltage'  How is this XL6009 and MT3608? https://amzn.to/2nf6L2U https://amzn.to/2vGTFzz

Comment: Datasheets don't not specify the dropout voltage https://www.sunrom.com/get/283300 https://www.olimex.com/Products/Breadboarding/BB-PWR-3608/resources/MT3608.pdf They are LM2596/76 clones, so I doubt they have better parameters than the original.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of LM2596(Buck converter) you should use XL6019 buck-boost converter. As Lead-acid provide voltage between 14.2v (Full charge) to 10.8 (at 90% discharge).

So XL6019 can automatically step-up and step-down these voltages for 12v fix output